# Fallout shelter: Where does the mystery man appear

Tags: fallout-shelter

I need to know how to quickly find the Mystery Man. He's a good way to get caps but is very rare in my vault.
 
As in, like three times a month.

Any ways to find Mr Mystery quickly?

Comment: Three times a month?! He turns up every five minutes while I'm playing, though I usually don't bother to go looking for him.

Answer (score 1):

If he appears in an elevator, it will be lit (green), so you can zoom out for a quick check.

Otherwise there's not really a strategy, other than picking a zoom level that lets you scan all your rooms efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the sound of him matters. If it was loud, he appeared somewhere near, maybe higher or lower. If it was barely heard -- it should be somewhere to the left or right. Also headphones help.

Comment: He makes a sound? What does it sound like? When?

Comment: @DCShannon there are 3 piano notes that play as he appears, the same 3 that play in the actual game https://youtu.be/gAmOSIwe86E

Comment: As a side note, my Galaxy S7 vibrates when he appears, too